# Recyclerview not scolling smoothly when different viewholders are used

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am creating a chat application which will have different types of layouts inflated depending on the kind of message received. Each viewholder has its own layout and implementation. The application works fine except for the fact that it lags when scrolling, especially at the point which the layout type changes.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (itemType) {
        case Const.CHAT_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NOTIFY:
            ((NotifyViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_DATE_HEADER:
            ((DefaultDateHeaderViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_TEXT_MESSAGE:
            ((OutgoingViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case -VIEW_TYPE_TEXT_MESSAGE:
            ((IncomingViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            ((OutgoingImageViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case -VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            ((IncomingImageViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_ATTACHMENT:
            ((OutgoingAttachmentViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
        case -VIEW_TYPE_ATTACHMENT:
            ((IncomingAttachmentViewHolder) holder).bindData(position);
            break;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong message view type. Please, report this issue on GitHub with full stacktrace in description.");
}



@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Const.CHAT_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NOTIFY:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notify_bubble, parent, false);
            return new NotifyViewHolder(row);
        case VIEW_TYPE_DATE_HEADER:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_date_header, parent, false);
            return new NotifyViewHolder(row);
        case VIEW_TYPE_TEXT_MESSAGE:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.outgoing_bubble, parent, false);
            return new OutgoingViewHolder(row);
        case -VIEW_TYPE_TEXT_MESSAGE:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.incoming_bubble, parent, false);
            return new IncomingViewHolder(row);
        case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_outcoming_image_message, parent, false);
            return new OutgoingImageViewHolder(row);
        case -VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE_MESSAGE:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_incoming_image_message, parent, false);
            return new IncomingImageViewHolder(row);
        case VIEW_TYPE_ATTACHMENT:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_outcoming_attachment, parent, false);
            return new OutgoingAttachmentViewHolder(row);
        case -VIEW_TYPE_ATTACHMENT:
            row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_incoming_attachment, parent, false);
            return new IncomingAttachmentViewHolder(row);
    }


    return null;
}
```

Is there a way to implement a smooth scrolling layout that inflates different layouts?